# What is the best way to disable scroll in one direction on React Native

Tags: scroll, react-native

I've a simple ScrollView and i would like to disabled scroll to top.

```
<ScrollView 
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    onScroll={(e) => this.setState({ scrollY: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y}) }
    style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}
>
    <PostList />
</ScrollView>
```

Example :

User cannot scroll top if height is equal 0, but can scroll top if height is more than 0

So what is the best way to disable scroll in a direction ?

Comment: You only want to allow user to scroll the list downwards, but once they've scrolled down, they can no longer scroll back up?

Comment: @jevakallio i would like user cannot scroll before height 0 or width 0 for example

Comment: It's still quite hard to understand the requirement. Maybe you could write a bit more fleshed out example, that might improve your chances of getting a great answer.

Comment: @jevakallio i've edited my post and add an example